# Zend Framework 2/3 Secure REST API

Tags: rest, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am trying to build a zend framework application tied to angular. So I am thinking to go with the RESTful approach. Do you have any references on examples on how to this securely?

Comment: You'r question is too broad and doesn't have a concrete answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at Apigility (Created by Zend and built on top of the framework) https://apigility.org/ if you want to build RESTful API's with Zend Framework.

If you want to build APIs direct with Zend Framework you could lift a lot of ideas for authentication and authorization from the Apilgity docs https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/intro